# jQuery Target Counting Class (Ex. $('.class0') ..... $('.class1');.....$('.class2');.... ect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

I'm having an issue with a shopping cart system that was poorly designed. It adds a class to the row with the shopping cart details. However it counts with the number of items in the cart, and they did not add a separate class for styling.

It works similar to this

```
<tr class="proddetails0"><td>Product 0</td></tr>

<tr class="proddetails1"><td>Product 1</td></tr>

<tr class="proddetails2"><td>Product 2</td></tr>
```

Below is an exacty snip of the mess this thing is! I need to target these table rows so i can clone and replace them for a mobile layout solution. It wasn't built mobile first so i'm stuck with the task of integrating bootstrap!

YOUR HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED. Also, does anyone know a js plugin that will replace a table with a BS table layout? That would be hugely helpful!

```
<tr valign="top" class="ShoppingCartRow0" style="height: 50px;">
<td align="center"> 

<label for="quantity_0" class="aural-only">Quantity </label>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="3" value="15" name="quantity_0_1061" id="quantity_0" onkeypress="return submitEnter(document.getElementById('UPDATE_CART'),event);" class="form-control">
<div><input type="submit" class="btn-convio" name="remove_0_1061" id="remove_0_1061" value="Remove"></div>
</td>
<td>    

<h5><span class="CartItemName">Desert</span></h5>
($25.00 each)
<div>
<table class="CartItemConfig" cellpadding="2">

<tbody><tr valign="top" style="height: 50px;">
<td width="40%" align="right" style="padding-right: 15px;"><u><span class="CartItemConfigLabel">Pickup Location</span></u></td>
<td align="left" style="background-color: rgb(243, 243, 241); border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px;"><span class="CartItemConfigValue">2 p.m.  5 p.m. Tuesday, Dallas</span></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</div>


<div><a class="Smaller" href="site/Ecommerce/1986741958?EDIT_ITEM=true&amp;item=item_0_1061&amp;store_id=1241#ConfigForm">Edit this item</a></div>

</td>
<td align="right">

<p>$375.00</p>

</td>
</tr>
```

Would this be done using a for/each loop?

Using "i" ?

```
<div id="prod_row_hack" class="row hidden-lg">
 <div id="append_prod_here" class="col-xs-11 col-centered">


 </div>
</div>



<script>

var myClass = "ShoppingCartRow";
var finalclass = myClass + (i++) __________ ( Note**, However many times it's found )

foreach {
$('append_prod_here').append('<div class="row">' + finalclass clone + '</div>');
}

</script>
```

Am i stretching the boundaries of jQuery?

P.S. Bonus points if you can guess the name of this Sh*T system i'm forced to use

Thanks again!

Comment: Is it the only thing in the table? and if there are no other classes, you can just use a attribute starts with selector.

Comment: There are multiple <tr> elements before and after. Can you please elaborate though, i might be able to use this as part of a larger solution.

Comment: `$("td[class*='proddetails']")`

Comment: DUDE! No way, you can substr() with css?? I had no idea! Wow! I def learned something new today! This is an amazing solution!